# Why is a double 0.1 only imprecise AFTER arithmetics

Tags: c#, floating-point

```
double d = 0.1;
float f = 0.1F;
Console.WriteLine(d == f);
```

is false. Wich makes sense because of imprecisions.

```
Console.WriteLine(d*d);
```

prints: 0.010000000000000002

but why can't I see the imprecision before arithmetics?

```
String.Format("{0:0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}", d)
```

is still precisely 0.10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Where is the imprecision here?

Edit after close of question:
this is not the same as [is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).
The answer given in the linked question is precisely the behavior the questioner was expecting.
The question is why it does NOT behave as expected after the initial assignment.

Comment: Because printing the precise, encoded value for 0.1 would be incredibly inconvenient for 99.9999% of applications, so floating point APIs work very hard to preserve “intended” values.